# Show the height of an $n$ block formation is $O(\sqrt{n})$, where each layer has strictly fewer blocks than the one under it

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics

**Question**: Blocks of height one are stacked in layers in some formation. Each layer has strictly fewer blocks than the one under it. Show the height of an $n$ block formation is $O(\sqrt{n})$.

**Attempt/Thoughts**:

For $n=1$, there is one formation, a formation of height $1$ with $1$ block in the only layer.

For $n=2$, there is one formation, a formation of height $1$ with $2$ blocks in the only layer.

For $n=3$, there is only one formation, a formation of height $2$ with 2 blocks in the lowest layer, and $1$ block in the highest layer.

For $n=4$, there is only one formation, a formation of height $2$ with $3$ blocks in the lowest layer, and $1$ block in the highest layer.

Another way to phrase this problem is to say for a positive integer $n$, show that the longest strictly increasing partition of $n$ contains $O(\sqrt{n})$ terms. I'm not sure how to show this, any hints appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a fixed height $h$ the *minimum* number of blocks you can have in a formation is fairly easily seen to be $\frac{h(h+1)}2$, with a side-$h$ triangle of blocks. Thus $n$ is $\Omega(h^2)$, implying $h$ is $O(\sqrt n)$.

Comment: I'm unsure what you mean by a side-h triangle of blocks.

Comment: @IntegrateThis $h$ blocks at the bottom. Then each layer has exactly one less block than the layer below it, culminating in the top layer having $1$ block.

Comment: Please do not make [changes like that](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/97462/revisions) to my answers.